# How to select this table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql

I have this database table 'market'

```
id       market_id       shows       clicks        event       data
 1          158          1000         300           on       2012-03-01
 2          158          1500         600           off      2012-03-14
 3          158          1500         600           on       2012-03-14
 4          158          2500         700           off      2012-03-20
```

I want to select it and get array like this:

```
$array  = array (
            array('from 2012-03-01 to 2012-03-14' => array('shows' => 500, 'clicks' => 300)
            array('from 2012-03-14 to 2012-03-20' => array('shows' => 1000, 'clicks' => 100)
```

How to do that? Have I do that in Mysql or have I do that in php?

edit:

'shows' in array calculates like that  1500 - 1000, 1500 is from table where 'event' is *off* and 1000 is from table where 'event' is *on*, click's calculate same.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Read something about PHP and MySQL. Or search for "PHP fetch mysql database".
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/4 Google is your friend...

Comment: what is 500 and 100 for field shows and same thing for clicks. How they are being calculated?

Comment: I think the `shows` value for the second array is 1000 not 100, i.e the difference between the `shows` and the `clicks` for the two range dates.

Comment: Anyhow 2012-03-14 should not be considered for both date range to remove redundancy. it should be like  2012-03-01 to 2012-03-14 and 2012-03-015 to 2012-03-20 or a weekly report can be generated. Also your calculation does not seem to be correct. if 500 is coming for 2012-03-14 like subtracting 1500-1000 then there is another record having shows 1000  for date 2010-03-01. How it will be calculated for 2010-03-01

Comment: This very sound like "do the developer's job I'm paid for, for me please".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat: I can't really work out what your *intention* is and hence there may be much better solutions that this but...
Here's a query that works on your sample data.

```
SELECT
    t2.data as from_date,
    t1.data as to_date,
    (t1.shows-t2.shows) as shows,
    (t1.clicks - t2.clicks) as clicks
FROM `market` t1
    inner join market t2 
        on (t1.market_id=t2.market_id and t1.event='off' and t2.event='on' and t1.data>t2.data)
    left join market t3 
        on (t1.data>t3.data and t3.event='on' and t3.data>t2.data)
WHERE t3.id is null
```

To explain a little bit: the query joins the table onto it self to find all pairs of rows where one represents an "off" event that is later than an "on" event. This picks up all pairs (even 2012-03-20 'off' and 2012-03-01 'on') so then we do a LEFT JOIN again to check there are no other 'on' events between the 'on' row and the 'off' row.

btw, I think there's an error in your sample results. The values for "shows" in your second result should be 1000.

Comment: @DonatasVeikutis I would highly recommend analysing exactly what you're trying to do as I suspect you're not going about it in the best way - particular in terms of how you're storing your data.